# QT QTcpServer listen

Tags: qt, qtcpserver, qhostaddress

i have a question about QT QTcpServer server->listen(QHostAddress, qint16). I have problems with the address.

I tried with QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"), and that worked. I tried with QHostAddress::Any, and that failed (error 10, not supported). I tried with QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, and that failed (same error). I tried with QHostAddress("0.0.0.0"), and that failed, with same error. I tried with the address of the interface, that worked.

```
NotificationServer::NotificationServer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {     
    server = new QTcpServer(this); 
    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newConnection())); 
    if (!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, port)) { 
        qDebug() << "Server could not start." << server->serverError(); 
        server = nullptr; 
    } else { 
        qDebug() << "Server started."; 
    } 
}
```

It seems, that it is not possible making the QTcpServer listen on all interfaces. OS is Linux XUbuntu. How can i make the server listen at all interfaces?

Comment: QHostAddress::Any should work. Which version of Qt do you use? Can you provide a proper implementation of your code?

Comment: The version is some 5.something. 

    NotificationServer::NotificationServer(QObject *parent) :     
    QObject(parent)
    {

        server = new QTcpServer(this);
        connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, 
            SLOT(newConnection()));
        if (!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, port)) {
             qDebug() << "Server could not start." << 
                server->serverError();
             server = nullptr;
        } else {
             qDebug() << "Server started.";
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry, how to format code?

Comment: BTW, if that matters: The XUbuntu is running in a VMWare virtual machine, running on Windows

Comment: When you write something like `server->listen(QHostAddress("10.10.0.10"), port)`, here 10.10.0.10 is an example of an interface ip, it works right?

Comment: Yes. Any valid IPv4 address works, except 0.0.0.0
("valid" means existing interface :) )

Comment: How did you configure `VMWare` _network options_? **Nat** or **Bridged** ?

Comment: First: NAT. Second: Named Network (VM Network)